# macOS: How to keep an app and its new windows/dialogs always hidden?

Tags: macos, window-manager, ui

I am running a 3rd party app on my Mac that spawns new small in-app windows/dialogs/popups almost every 3 seconds, to show the progress of a specific command. These windows are closed automatically by the application.

The problem is that these in-app windows are shown on top of other apps. Is there a way of keeping them hidden all the time (I don't care about the shown progress)?

I have tried to hide the app itself, but it gets back to the visible state along with its in-app windows. There is no Hide option available in the app.

What can I do to handle this?

Comment: Not sure if the app grabs attention by switching to itself, but you can try by creating a new desktop and let the app remain visible there all the time.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Well, that is simple and it works! If you convert the comment into an answer, I will approve it (not sure if this is the right procedure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient workaround would be to create a new desktop, move the app along with all the app windows to it and, leave it visible/maximized there.

If the app doesn't automatically steals focus to itself, this approach can resolve your issue.